# Should chat rooms be limited to one room per post?

Tags: feature-request, chat

Example: [This comment](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/114546/how-can-i-convince-graduate-students-in-china-to-not-copy-paste-from-the-interne#comment301091_114556) links to [this chat room](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/114546/how-can-i-convince-graduate-students-in-china-to-not-copy-paste-from-the-interne#comment301091_114556) which contains [this "let's continue the conversation in chat"](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80976/discussion-between-xuq01-and-nat) link to a room which duplicates much of the original conversation.

Limiting chat rooms to one per post would solve two problems:

1. It would eliminate the `C H A T C E P T I O N` effect illustrated above, and
2. It would allow mods the ability to move comments to the canonical chat for a given post more than once (currently, Move to Chat only works the first time you use it on a given post).

Thoughts?

Comment: I don't know if it should be *limited*. But it should certainly (by default) just link to the already existing room.

Comment: You'd need to make sure that if the existing room for that post is frozen, the room can either be thawed out or a new room created (with the prevention of additional rooms limited to when another room is currently active).

Comment: Is this a common occurrence? I've never seen it happen aside from your example.

Comment: @KevinB: The second problem is very common. Less common but still troublesome is the inscrutable behavior of the "Comments are not for extended discussion, would you like to move this conversation to chat" link, which could be greatly simplified if chat rooms were consolidated into one per post.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the conversation between two users is a small subset of a larger set of comments, so you get the case where the 8 comments between those users got moved to one room and then a mod wants to move the other 30 comments to chat.  But "move to chat" creates a new room, as you said.

Rather than adding comments to a room called "Discussion between X and Y", it'd be better to make the general room for the post ("discussion on $title") *from all the original comments*, including the ones that got moved to the sidebar.  If nothing else has happened in the other room then it can be absorbed into the main one; if, on the other hand, X and Y are 50 messages into a discussion of their own that's not even about the original post any more, as sometimes happens, you wouldn't want to pull all that back in.  X and Y thought they were having a side chat and that's a reasonable thing for them to think; their conversation shouldn't be yanked back into the main one for the post.

This would all be pretty hard to automate, though, because somebody (or some code) needs to *make a decision about the existing room*.  I think we're just going to have to live with *chatception* as the less-bad option.  Messages from the users' room can always be moved into the main room, if somebody flags to request it.